# How to solve cascaded transistors to get gain, Rin and Rout by hand analysis?

Tags: transistors, amplifier

[image]

I am having a problem calculating the requirements for this circuit, I can't figure out how to calculate the small signal model or the values of the resistances Rpi for both transistors.

Comment: Explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: With a cap directly between emitter and ground, the gain is going to be unpredictable anyway.  Ditch this mess and find a circuit designed by someone competent.

Comment: The cap is there to provide an AC path to ground for the emitter.

Comment: @Andyaka  My problem states that i should calculate the Gain Rin and Rout for this circuit and compare them with simulation results from Multisim.

Comment: Why was this put on hold? Who are the piss-poor engineering idiots that thought this was confusing?  Id answer it just fine if it wasnt locked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hand analysis, start by assuming the base currents are zero.  The base of the first transistor is about 1V, because of the 220k 27k voltage divider.  First emitter is about 0.3V because of Vbe drop.  Since assuming Ib=0 Ie=Ic.  Ie = 0.3/1500 = 200uA.  Voltage across the 10k is 200uA x 10000 = 2V.  So Vc = 9-2 = 7V.  So the emitter follower Ve = 7 - 0.7 = 6.3V.

If you need to be more accurate than this, you can use the Beta of the transistor to calculate Ib form Ic.  You can also update Vbe based on the current.  Then redo the whole smash including the Ib in the first base calculation and Vbe in the emitter voltage calculation.  This is almost never necessary.

Now gm is approximatly Ic/Vt or about .008 at comfortable temperatures.  r_pi = Beta/gm.  r_o = Va/Ic.  So you need to know Beta and the early voltage to complete this.